# ASP.NET Web Api with Backbone.js Simple Login and Logout

Tags: visual-studio-2012, backbone.js, authentication, asp.net-web-api, logout

I am using visual studio 2012, M.V.C 4, Web-Api 2 and Backbone.js at client side which consumes my asp.net web-api. i am trying to build a simple Login and Logout page.

I have done a lot of Google search to perform such operation but i am not able to find a simple login and logout operation using asp.net web api.

What is the simplest and right way to perform a Login and logout operation ASP.NET Web-Api and backbone.js

Comment: I am also trying the basic authentication in asp.net web-api. but still i am not getting how it will work?? please help me with it. Just simple login and logout using asp.net web-api and Backbone.js at client side!!